# Full-Factorial Design (3^2): Not sure about right method for analysis

Tags: regression, anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design, conjoint-analysis

I ran an experiment (online-survey) showing venture capitalists 9 fictional startups that only differed in factor 1 and factor 2. Both factors had three levels: Factor 1 = 50,250,450; Factor 2 = 0.5,1,5.2,5. The dependent variable was the value of the company in Mio. EUR.
Every venture capitalists answered the exact same order of cases, so there must be correlation with the answers of each person.

I'm interested in the main effects of factor 1 and factor 2 as well as the interaction between the levels of factor 1 and factor 2.

My sample size is small n=34 which is ok for venture capital research.

My problem is that I'm not sure which analysis I should run with respect to my experimental design.

I tried multiple things: regression, anova with repeated measures (however I was not able to perform it properly in STATA with repeated measures of two variables, conjoint analysis but am not satisfied with my results.

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: I do not use Stata but I am surprised that a repeated measures design with nine observations per participant is unanalysable. Perhaps you should try posting your code on a Stata-specific site for help?

Comment: Unfortunately, I searched all sources for STATA help, but no useful results. What works is the ANOVA in STATA if I only analyze if my 9 treatments are causing the variability in the dependent variable or if this is due to variance between the participants. However every treatment is a unique combination of f1 and f2 so I want to do a Two-Way ANOVA afterwards. At this point, I'm not able to control for the between-participants-error using the repeat-command:(